# Add org-mode clocktable column that is the product of a constant and the Time column

Tags: org-mode, org-table, org-clock-table

Here's a snippet from an optimistic org-mode file

```
#+CONSTANTS: rate=100000.0

#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :narrow 60! :header "#+NAME: billed #+attr_latex: :align l|r|r|r|r :environment longtable :font \\footnotesize\n"
#+NAME: billed #+attr_latex: :align l|r|r|r|r :environment longtable :font \footnotesize
| Headline                                                  | Time   |      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*                                              | *0:07* |      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+------|
| <2016-08-04 Thu>                                          | 0:07   |      |
| \_  Doing things |        | 0:07 |
#+END:

* <2016-08-04 Thu> 
** Doing things
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2016-08-04 Thu 19:23]--[2016-08-04 Thu 19:30] =>  0:07
:END:
```

I'd like to add a column that's the product of the rate constant and the Time column.

Adding something like

```
:function \"@2$3=$rate*@2$2\"
```

inside the header, or adding similar to a #+TBLFM before #+END has no effect. In the latter case the #+TBLFM line is removed after I doing

```
org-dblock-update
```